# Is there a way to implement DatePicker with a Monthly calendar view in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, datepicker, ionic4

I am trying to build a form in Ionic framework (Ver 5.2.4) which needs a date-picker . The default date-picker avaliable in Ionic is the scrollable one but I need to implement it as a calendar view 
Is there a way to do that?  I would be grateful if  someone could point me the right direction.

I have tried using these solutions: 
https://market.ionicframework.com/plugins/ionicdatepicker

Answer (score 0):

You posted the ionic cli version you use but not which ionic version so I assume you are using version 4.

A date picker like this is a [common request](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/get-calendar-view-for-datepicker-in-ionic/100929) and the best practice seems to use a custom component. 
Looking around I only found the following two for version 4:

[2](https://github.com/write2sv/ionic4-date-picker) and [3](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-implement-calendar-in-ionic/106729/7).

If they don't work you could try and implement one on your own as described [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-implement-calendar-in-ionic/106729/7).

Hope this helps.